# Why PHP can't see an uploaded file?

Tags: php, html, apache

I have an `index.php` and `upload.php`. In `index.php` is a `form action="upload.php"` with `input type="file" id="file" name="file"` tag in it. PHP code is:

```
<?php
$file = $_FILES['file'];
print_r($file);
echo "test";
?>
```

For some reason it shows `echo` but `print_r()` doesn't work.

I've tried rewriting the code. Adding other identificators for the `input` tag inside `index.php` but it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When trying ```print_r($_POST)``` it shows ```Array([file] => filename.jpg)```. So it can find the file, but the problem is that a have more code to move that file in another directory, and trying ```print_r($_FILES)``` for some reason doesn't show the file, it shows ```Array()```

Comment: @wxnzks I'm curious.  What if you tried `var_export($_FILES);`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Really.  Someone says `print_r($_FILES)` for some reason doesn't show the file, it shows Array().  And your reply is " I ment [sic] `print_r($_FILES)`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are forgot  enctype="multipart/form-data"

try this version

```html
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p><input type="file" name="file">
  <p><button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Maybes are best suggested as a comment, as they are not really an answer

Comment: @RiggsFolly Where is your answer?

Comment: @Misunderstood As yet, I dont have one. I am asking for more information. I dont provide answers until the OP provides a reasonable amount of usable information

Comment: @RiggsFolly So you are saying you could not understand the OP is having an issue with uploading a file? You have no solution?  I have more respect for Ramil for at least trying to help.  And Ramil is correct.  And you criticize him for trying to be polite?

Comment: Yeah I actually forgot to put it in. Thank you both!

Comment: I really like this. When someone like @RiggsFolly criticizes someone's answer and it is the answer that helps the OP the most.  Ramil, you are a gentleman and a scholar.

Comment: @Misunderstood if you look at the comment I did not criticise the answer, just the fact that at the time of posting it was a guess, note the text "**maybe** you are forgot" The process should be to ask the questioner a question like _"would you show us the `<form>` line from your page please"_ and then look for a duplicate or close the question as a typo.

Comment: Rationalize all you want.  It no longer says "Maybe".  May you should have edited rather than make an antagonistic comment.

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention what type of file is being uploaded.  Here is an example of a image upload. With multiple image selections allowed.

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Get a Photo from your device <br>
<input type="file" name="image1[]" multiple accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/webp" /><br>
<button type="submit">Upload Photo</button>
</form>
```

And the upload PHP:

```
foreach ($_FILES["image1"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == 0 ) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["image1"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = basename($_FILES["image1"]["name"][$key]);
        $result = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
        if($result == false){echo "not moved\n";}
    }
    if($error > 0){echo "error $error\n";}
}
```

To ascertain the type of image uploaded:

```
 switch(strtolower($_FILES['image1']['type'])){
  case 'image/jpeg':
    $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
    if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
  case 'image/png':
    $image = @imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
    if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
  case 'image/gif':
    $image = @imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
    if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
  case 'image/webp':
    $image = @imagecreatefromwebp($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
    if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
  default:
    $img = @getimagesize($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
    switch(strtolower($img['mime'])){
    case 'image/jpeg':
      $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
      if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
    case 'image/png':
      $image = @imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
      if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
    case 'image/gif':
      $image = @imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
      if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
    default:
      $filename = $_FILES['image1']['name'];
      $ext = substr($filename,-3);
      switch(strtolower($ext)){
      case 'jpg':
        $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
        if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
      case 'ebp':
        $image = @imagecreatefromwebp($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
        if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
      case 'gif':
        $image = @imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
        if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
      case 'png':
        $image = @imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
        if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
      default:
        $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
        if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
        $image = @imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
        if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
        $image = @imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
        if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can already upload the file, such as using form like the following:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p><input type="file" name="file">
  <p><button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then if you want to display the image at the receiving "upload.php", you may use:

If the image is JPG/JPEG type:

```
<?php
$string1= base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]));

echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, ' .  $string1  . '"/>';

?>
```

If the image is PNG type:

```
<?php
$string1= base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]));

echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64, ' .  $string1  . '"/>';

?>
```

Note: actually we usually save the uploaded file in the server (for later display), or store the binary data into a BLOB field in a db table, but the above code is to demonstrate how one can do to immediately display the uploaded image.

Comment: This is all good. But you should try to ascertain the type of image that was uploaded.  Or use the accept clause to limit the type of image to be uploaded.   And I do not think it is a good idea to depend on the file extension.  I updated my answer to show how I get the image type.